# How do I rename the existing file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So after I record something with MediaRecorder and put it somewhere in the android device. How do I then rename that file? This is the closest I've got to a solution. After I click the button, nothing happens.

```
public void nameAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder nameAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    nameAlert.setMessage("Name of your recorded file:");
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    nameAlert.setView(input);

    nameAlert.setPositiveButton("Enter", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            newFileName = input.getText();
            String currentFileName = externalStoragePath;
            currentFileName = currentFileName.substring(1);
            Log.i(storagePath, currentFileName);

            File directory = new File (externalStoragePath);
            File from = new File (directory, currentFileName);
            File to = new File (directory, newFileName + ".mp3");
            from.renameTo(to);
        }
    });
    nameAlert.show();
```

Also, this might be relevant.

```
externalStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Log:

```
08-02 02:04:03.623: I/(14043): storage/emulated/0
```

Comment: Your code is pretty much as simple as it can get.

Comment: @SmartLemon any idea what could be wrong, though?

Comment: Wheres the code for the onclick?

Comment: @SmartLemon I edited the original post

Comment: Is the alert dialog being shown?

Comment: And is the log happening.

Comment: @SmartLemon yes, the dialog is being shown and the log is being shown also, check the original post again for log

Comment: `java.io.File.renameTo` returns a boolean value indicating whether the rename succeeded or not. You might want to check whether that is returning true or false.

Comment: @AlexMDC do you mean like, inserting that into log? Tried that but it doesn't work

Comment: Try `Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(from.renameTo(to)));`

Comment: @SmartLemon it says false, I'm guessing that means that the rename operation haven't succeeded. Any idea then how could i approach fixing it?

Comment: Yep, I will come back to this after lunch :)

Comment: Whats the definition of `externalStoragePath`

Comment: @SmartLemon sorry for the late reply, I'm pretty sure we're in different time zones :p do you mean which path it returns? log says it's storage/emulated/0

Comment: @SmartLemon just figured it out, I did a small mistake that caused the method to fail, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Im in New Zealand, and I was going to suggest that it was your problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! The problem was in this line:

```
File directory = new File (externalStoragePath);
```

I changed it to this:

```
File directory = new File (externalStoragePath + File.separator + "/Android/data/com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad/");
```

Because externalStoragePath returns the whole path (including the file name)

Answer (score 0):

According to [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) reference. Many failures are possible. Some of the more likely failures include:

1. Write permission is required on the directories containing both the source and destination paths.
2. Search permission is required for all parents of both paths.
3. Both paths be on the same mount point. On Android, applications are most likely to hit this restriction when attempting to copy between internal storage and an SD card.
   Note that this method does not throw IOException on failure. Callers must check the return value.

Could you double check one by one? I think you can find out what's going on.

Comment: Just figured it out, It  was none of those failures, check my answer, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Check first if the the file is excisting:
And if it still dont work it has to be done manualy

```
    if(to.exists()) throw new java.IOException("file exists");
    if (from.renameTo(to)) {
        //success
    }else{
        to.createNewFile();
        FileChannel FCfrom = null;
        FileChannel FCto = null;
        try {
            FCfrom = new FileInputStream(from).getChannel();
            FCto = new FileOutputStream(to).getChannel();
            long count = 0;
            long size = source.size();              
            while((count += destination.transferFrom(source, count, size-count))<size);
        }finally {
            if(FCto != null){
                FCto.close();
                FCfrom.close();
                from.delete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I just figured it out a second ago :) thanks anyway mate!